# Infinite Loop on Browser Resize With FlexSlider and $(window).resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider, window-resize, web-frontend

I wrote some JQuery code to refresh an instance of FlexSlider that I'm using on a responsive Wordpress home page. Because it's responsive the slider needs to reset every time the browser window is resized.

I saw on the docs that flexslider.resize(); is the built-in way to reset the slider.

e.g.

```
var headSlider = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider');
headSlider.resize();
```

I implemented a $(window).resize() method and I initially saw that it was firing hundreds of times per second and causing serious performance issues so I found some answers on StackOverflow, and ended up implementing this function that was provided by another user:

```
var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
    var timers = {};
    return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
      if (!uniqueId) {
        uniqueId = "uniqueIDdefault";
      }
      if (timers[uniqueId]) {
        clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
      }
      timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
  })();
```

This function seems to have helped, because the event is no longer firing hundreds of times per second. The issue I'm having now is that it appears to be looping. When I run flexSlider.resize() it seems to trigger the window.resize() function and I end up in an infinite resize loop..

I may be wrong, but it seems like maybe the .resize() function on flexslider is being crossed with the window.resize() JQuery function?? Am I right?? How do I fix this to save on performance.. I'm concerned that having infinite loops running in the background every half second is going to cause performance issues. Is there a better way to do this?

**My current code:**

```
$(window).load(function(){

  var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
    var timers = {};
    return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
      if (!uniqueId) {
        uniqueId = "uniqueIDdefault";
      }
      if (timers[uniqueId]) {
        console.log('>> timers[uniqueId] exists ',timers[uniqueId], uniqueId)
        clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
      }
      console.log('>> timers[uniqueId] exists ',timers[uniqueId], uniqueId)
      timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
  })();

  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    itemWidth: 980,
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("home-upcoming-featured").style.height = getHalfFeaturedHeight()+"px";  //hide by default

  //When the browser is resized, reset the height of the featured article stack visibility..
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    var headSlider = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider');
    if(!showToggle) {
      document.getElementById("home-upcoming-featured").style.height = getHalfFeaturedHeight()+"px"; 
      //getHalfFeaturedHeight() returns half the height of the content area.
    } else {
      document.getElementById("home-upcoming-featured").style.height = getFullFeaturedHeight()+"px"; 
      //getFullFeaturedHeight() returns the full height of the content area.
    }
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){
      console.log('>> resetting the slider...')
      $('.flexslider').resize();
    }, 500, "sliderresize");
  });
});
```

**My Console Logs:**

[image: Browser Console Logs]

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to call resize() on the flexslider instance, not on the jQuery element? I haven't used jQuery in *ages*, but I think this triggers a `resize` DOM event that bubbles up to the window.

So instead of:

```
waitForFinalEvent(function(){
  console.log('>> resetting the slider...')
  $('.flexslider').resize();
}, 500, "sliderresize");
```

try:

```
waitForFinalEvent(function(){
  console.log('>> resetting the slider...')
  headSlider.resize();
}, 500, "sliderresize");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. how would I target the specific instance? I thought var headSlider = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider'); was already doing that no?

Comment: I've added what I mean in the answer

Comment: Can you link me to the docs that mentioned resize()? Looking through the FlexSlider source code, it seems that `slider  = $(el)`, which is an odd choice that basically says `$('.flexslider').data('flexslider').resize()` would have the same effect as `$('.flexslider').resize()`, and thus cause the infinite loop. https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L13

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what version of FlexSlider you're using, but the one from the homepage http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ seems to be responsive out of the box with the minimal configuration? (Or maybe I have misunderstood your situation).

Comment: I was able to get it working by adding some code that records the window width and height and then checks if the window width and height have changed before allowing a new timeout to be set.. seems to be working... still not sure why a loop was being created, but thank you for your help :)

Comment: Just to answer to your questions.. I think I found the resize solution on StackOverflow, it may not have been explicitly stated in the docs. For some reason when I resize my browser window the slides stop lining up properly. I found some people with similar issues on Stack and the recommend solution was to run flexslider.resize(); to get the slider to reset the slides to the new dimensions. But I agree with you, it seems like it should just work out of the box? I'm not sure why it needs to be reset...

Answer (score 0):

the loop is created by you. because you are creating a new timeout. after you clear one.

```
timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
```

also unless you want to explicitly say, that you want to kill the timeout with the specified ID, you don't need the clearTimeout. as timeOut runs once.

if you don't want to create a loop. don't create a new timeout. the resize event will fire every time, you have resized the page when you can resize the slider.

also not sure why do you have 
`$('.flexslider').resize();` and `slider.resize();`
where is slider defined?

I think what you would want is:

```
  $( window ).resize(function() {
      ....
      $('.flexslider').resize();
  });
```

Comment: the new timer is only set when the window resize event is fired. It should eventually clear when the window is no longer being resized. The issue is that, for some reason. my flexslider.resize() code appears to be triggering a window.resize event within my window resize event listener which is creating a never ending loop. The loop is not being caused by my setTimeout. I'm not sure why this is happening, or how to prevent it with code. I suspect some kind of event propegation prevention technique is needed?